# Is there a way to copy or export the CDN Libraries from a Fiddle in JSFiddle to the HTML or ClipBoard

Tags: cdn, jsfiddle, code-snippets

Sorry if this is not an appropriate question, but I thought it would be worth asking because it seems a little nicer to create a snippet on SO than it is to provide an external link to JSFiddle or Codepen, etc.  I see that the Snippets thing allows for embedding some libraries, but Fiddle actually has a somewhat nicer interface, but I sort of started copying the Fiddles to a snippet on SO.  The problem with that is that if I use their CDN feature, I then have to copy those link and script tags into the HTML, or otherwise configure those on SO as well.

Maybe sort of a stupid question, and maybe just a matter of preference really, but I do like the snippets feature on SO also.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, you can simply do a curl request and store the results on your computer in a file.

```
curl https://some.file.on/the/internet.js > ./some_file.js
```